# Save request.user to an django extra view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Save request.user to an django extra view.

The example is from Django-Extra-Views. Seems to be working as the example states.

https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html

```
class OrderCreateView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Order
    inlines = [ItemsInline, TagsInline]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()
```

The following have been tried. They do not work.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # self.object = form.save()
    form.instance.owner = self.request.user
    form.save()
    return super(OrderCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

throws error:
 IntegrityError at /add/
 null value in column "owner_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Also tried adding it form.save

```
def save(self,  commit=True):
    instance = super(OrderCreateView, self).save(commit=False)
    instance.owner = self.request.user
    instance.save()


throws 
'OrderForm' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is having the issue, I was able to get it to work by adding the following to the View.

```
def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
    form.instance.owner = self.request.user
    return super(CreateView, self).forms_valid(form, inlines)
```